# Op-amp 'overcompensation'

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, ltspice, negative-feedback

First, a bit of background; I'm trying to regulate a HV DC-DC converter using an op-amp with an NPN Darlington current booster. The DC-DC converter is a push-pull circuit driven at about 40 kHz that boosts the voltage by a factor of around 200. The transformer centre tap is driven by the variable voltage from the op-amp / booster circuit. The circuit (without regulation) works as expected, the problem I'm having is trying to close the loop and achieve regulation - it's oscillating wildly.

Obviously because of the HV isolation and ripple requirements there's large leakage inductance and associated phase shift occurring in the DC-DC converter and voltage divider portions of the system. A quick calculation shows the leakage inductance and filter capacitance are going to cause unpredictable phase shifts starting around 4 kHz.

While reading the Art Of Electronics (excellent bedtime reading BTW!) I came across an example circuit that is essentially a precision 60 Hz power amplifier, using a mains transformer 'backwards' to boost a low voltage. See section 4.9.3 B and Figure 4.105. This circuit uses the LT1097 op-amp that features an 'overcompensation' pin to reduce the bandwidth of the loop and achieve stability with the horrible and unknowable phase shifts on the circuit's secondary. Unfortunately they don't give a value for the compensation cap.

So I guess my question is, can someone provide some more information about how to analyse this idea? Is there another way? The LM301 and NE5534 chips also look like they might be usable, having external compensation capability.

My understanding is that by 'overcompensating' the op-amp like this, you reduce the closed loop gain before poor phase margin can make the system unstable - the downside being lower bandwidth / slower step response.

Comment: Sounds interesting  Please add schematics/block diagram so we can better understand what exactly is going on and what you wish to do. In general, overcompensating sounds like making the minimum stable gain very much smaller than 1, e.g. 0.1 or less

Comment: This sounds very similar to a circuit I've built before: https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/HVPower1.png (image served from my website) compensation is the, oh dear I didn't use designators at the time, apologies -- the 0.01 + 100k in the middle, the 1/2 '358 is the error amp. Note the right side foldback current limiter for start up and short circuit protection.

Comment: Overcompensation is basically over-amplification which generally results in oscillation or ridiculous swinging of the output due to the lower bandwidth hence lower reaction speed. For example, a step load change of 0% to 100% will cause the output to undershoot but the undershoot amount will be too high due to the lower reaction speed, and the controller *overreacts* this and the output overshoots (as expected, the overshoot amount will be too high). There you have an oscillatory behaviour. Another possible behaviour is to have a "quasi-never-settling" output i.e. the output decay time is ...

Comment: ... too long that the output stays at an "unpredictable" value which means the output will be too low or too high, or the damped oscillations may take longer than expected *(I'm not quite sure about this, please someone verify)*, or even the output may stay oscillating.

Comment: Strange terminology, you usually compensate *more* to avoid oscillations, the external compensation amp are usually internally uncompensated for reaching maximum speed. Reducing loop bandwidth (*not* amp bandwidth) is easy even with standard amps (just chuck a capacitor in), but gain and phase margin should be evaluated to avoid oscillation. There are lots of resources on amplifier stability around. EDIT: the LT part uses the cap to have better slew rate